# What can't getpass take input from stdin?

Tags: c, passwords, glibc, termios

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char *password = getpass("Password: ");
    puts(password);
    return 0;
}
```

I see that getpass can not take input from stdin.

```
$ ./getpass <<< abc
Password:
xxx
```

It seems that this is related to termios. Could anybody show me the underlying code equivalent to this program on how this done?

Answer (score 1):

It's not that `getpass` "can not" read from `stdin`. It doesn't read from `stdin` because that's the way it's designed as its manpage indicates, it reads from `/dev/tty`:

> The `getpass()` function opens `/dev/tty` (the controlling terminal of the process), outputs the string `prompt`, turns off echoing, reads one line (the "password"), restores the terminal state and closes `/dev/tty` again.

An example of how to use the functions in `termios` to turn echoing off appears in Michael Kerrisk's excellent [The Linux Programming Interface](https://www.man7.org/tlpi/); the sample code is [available online](https://man7.org/tlpi/code/online/book/tty/no_echo.c.html).

Comment: Could you provide the exact equivalent code? The link you mentioned is not equivalent. It will just terminate if I pipe something to its stdin without waiting to take any input from the terminal.

Comment: The easiest way to get the behaviour of your program (reading from `/dev/tty` instead of `stdin`) is to reopen `stdin` as `/dev/tty`, which you can do by adding the line `    dup2(open("/dev/tty", O_RDWR), STDIN_FILENO);` just after the declaration of `buf`. You'll also need to add `#include <fcntl.h>` to the includes, in order to get the declaration of `open` and `O_RDWR`.

Comment: Is it exact the same as what `getpass()` does it?

Comment: Getpass doesn't reassign stdin, so no it's not identical. But I think it shows you all the things you need to know to write a function which does what you want. If there is something specific you don't know how to do, you could ask a specific question.

Comment: I just want to have the identical underlying code of password, but not just a similar one.

Comment: @user15483624: then find the source code for getpass and copy it. I was under the impression that you were trying to learn how to write the code. [Here's one which you can copy.](https://opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-167/gen.subproj/getpass.c.auto.html). Or if you want the Gnu version, [there's this one](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/misc/getpass.c.html).

Comment: No. this code is not standalone. It should not include internal function calls.

Comment: Many. For example, __fsetlocking

Comment: No. They only works on linux. But the original function getpass works on both linux and macos. The equivalent program should as compatible as getpass. That is what "equivalent" mean.

Comment: So `termios` can not be used as the base of both so that the same code can be used for both systems?